# .net core API optional route parameters

Tags: .net-core, swagger, swashbuckle

I have a .net core api with swagger. No I want to add a Filter-Class including optional filter-parameters.

```cs
[HttpGet("", Name ="get-index")]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(IEnumerable<MyModelGet>), (int)HttpStatusCode.OK)]
[ProducesResponseType(typeof(void), (int)HttpStatusCode.NoContent)]
public IActionResult GetIndex([FromRoute] MyFilter? filter){
    ...
}
```

The properties of the filter-class are optional/nullabel:

```cs
public class MyFilter {
    public int? size{
        get; set;
    } = null;
    ...
}
```

But in Swagger all Properties are required:

[image]

Is there any way (e.g. a Annotation) to make this fields optional?

Comment: The annotations seem to be wrong - the Name/Size/Page parameters are currently generated as *path* parameters, but they should probably be *query* parameters. See https://tkit.dev/2020/03/10/complex-get-query-param-objects-in-swashbuckle/ - does this help?

Comment: Oh yes, my issue was to use the Annotation ```[FromRoute]```. Using ```[FromQuery]``` solved my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing the `[FromRoute]` by `[FromQuery]` solved my issue.